# Android ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, android

Доброго времени суток, есть сайт на ASP.net в нём пару select-ов, все они объединены, т.е. при выборе первого селекта, появляются данные для второго, выбираем второй, появляются данные в третьем каждый выбор идёт через пост запрос. Пост запросе сохранятся данные предыдущего поля, когда выбираю последний селект, пост запрос идёт уже со всеми ранее выбранным полями.

Так вот вопрос, как отправить пост запрос?

Использую такое вот:

```
    String url="http://myurl/Default.aspx";
      DefaultHttpClient cliente=new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
      List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Select1", "1"));
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Select2", "2"));
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Select3", "3"));
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Select4", "4"));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
      HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(post);
```

Но происходит ошибка выполнения запрос со страницы :(

Comment: причем тут Android?

Comment: да и asp.net не приделах.

Comment: не важно на чем сайт, не важно на чем клиент, просмотри что шлет сервер, что шлет ему страница и просто отправь точно такой же запрос

Comment: ребята если бы было всё так просто, я бы сюда не писал, по сниффу отправляю такие же данные, но вот загвоздка в ASP.net странице есть ключи или что то типа того
__viewstate и там ещё одно

Comment: видимо придется делать в несколько приходов. По select'у за раз.